# To run "pylint" tool on multiple Python files on Windows Machine

Tags: windows, pylint

I want to run "pylint" tool on multiple python files present under one directory.
I want one consolidated report for all the Python files.

I am able to run individually one python file, but want to run on bunch of files.
Please help with the command for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a windows user, but isn't "pylint directory/*.py" enough ?

If the directory is a package (in the PYTHONPATH), you may also run "pylint directory"

Comment: I have already tried to run it in the way:

pylint "<Directory>/*.py".

But it not able to generate the report and giving output as 
"F:  1, 0: No module named <Directory>\*.py (fatal)".

Thanks

Comment: @Shaan pylint doesn't interpret '*.py' by itself, this is a job for the shell. Yoy may try to remove surrounding quotes

Answer (score 0):

Someone wrote a [wrapper in python 2](https://gist.github.com/gregorynicholas/3152237) to handle this

The code :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
'''
Module that runs pylint on all python scripts found in a directory tree..
'''

import os
import re
import sys

total = 0.0
count = 0

def check(module):
  '''
  apply pylint to the file specified if it is a *.py file
  '''
  global total, count

  if module[-3:] == ".py":

    print "CHECKING ", module
    pout = os.popen('pylint %s'% module, 'r')
    for line in pout:
      if  re.match("E....:.", line):
        print line
      if "Your code has been rated at" in line:
        print line
         score = re.findall("\d+.\d\d", line)[0]
        total += float(score)
        count += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    print sys.argv   
    BASE_DIRECTORY = sys.argv[1]
  except IndexError:
    print "no directory specified, defaulting to current working directory"
    BASE_DIRECTORY = os.getcwd()

  print "looking for *.py scripts in subdirectories of ", BASE_DIRECTORY 
  for root, dirs, files in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for name in files:
      filepath = os.path.join(root, name)
      check(filepath)

  print "==" * 50
  print "%d modules found"% count
  print "AVERAGE SCORE = %.02f"% (total / count)
```